# Error while compling vlc for android ,was it about libtool version?

Tags: vlc, libtool, autoreconf

I have downloaded vlc source code .
after running script below

```
sh compile.sh
```

I got an error

```
mkdir -p -- /root/workspace/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal && cd png && autoreconf -fiv -I/root/workspace/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /root/workspace/android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/share/aclocal --force -I scripts
configure.ac:66: error: Libtool version 2.4.2 or higher is required
scripts/libtool.m4:46: LT_PREREQ is expanded from...
configure.ac:66: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 63
aclocal: /usr/local/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 63
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 63
make: *** [.png] Error 63
```

I thought it was about libtool version ,but the problem remains after i installed libtool 2.4.2

can somebody kindly tell me what's the problem going on .

Best regards!

Eric Shen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though my ubuntu had the libtool2.4.2 installed, I too encountered this problem. This workaround solved the issue.

Find LT_PREREQ([2.4.2]) in one of the configure.ac files and replace it with LT_PREREQ([2.4])